# Можно ли в phpQuery парсить страницу снизу вверх?

Tags: php, curl, phpquery

Для парсинга использую curl + phpQuery. В процессе работы возникла необходимость парсить элементы страницы снизу вверх. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Запрос `phpQuery` возвращает вам массив каких-то элементов. Обходите массив с последнего элемента к первому. Либо циклом `for` либо сначала переверните массив и затем `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итерируйтесь по выбранным элементам в обратном порядке

```
$elements = $pq->find('...');
for ($i = count($elements); $i > 0; $i--) {
   // $elements[$i]
}
```